# How to mapping that tables using NHibernate (Fluent or XML)

Tags: nhibernate, database-design, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Can you help-me with that database :

[image]

I´m using Fluent NHibernate, but XML helps too...
My problem is with **ProductPrice** table...

Thanks

Paul

Comment: Why don't you start and ask about specific issues? You are basically asking the community to do everything for you.

Comment: My problem is only with ProductPrice table... The other tables is only to show all involved tables...

Comment: OK, I'll help you with that then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing special...

```
<class name="ProductPrice">
  <id name="Id">
    <generator class="..."/>
  </id>
  <property name="Price"/>
  <property name="IsSale"/>
  <property name="PriceSale"/>
  <property name="Sku"/>
  <many-to-one name="ProductSize" column="SizeProductFk"/>
  <many-to-one name="ColorProduct" column="ColorProductFk" />
</class>
```

Of course you have to map ProductSize and ColorProduct as entities.

Comment: Thanks Diego...
But I have another problem... Example: How can I get all ProductPrice with Product Id = 4 per example? 

Maybe my database design is not good/corret to solve that problem easyly...

Comment: HQL example: `from ProductPrice pp where pp.ProductSize.Product.id = 4`. There's nothing wrong with your design.

Comment: Thanks...
But in some cases the product has no color or size... So, How can I get his price?

Comment: If a product can have no color or size, then you're missing a relationship between price and product.

Comment: Which kind of relationship are you talking about?

Comment: @Paul, You have to state your requirements up front. If a Product can have a price without Size nor Color, then your DB design is wrong, no matter how you query it.

Comment: Yes... Do you have any suggestion ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you need a direct relationship from ProductPrice to Product. You can keep the relationships to ProductSize and ColorProduct, or map directly to Product, Color and Size (in which case you might end removing ProductSize and ColorProduct, depending on your needs)

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate now supports JPA (called NPersistence or NPA for the .NET platform) including JPA annotations. 
It is the best way to map entities and have your code portable for other vendors as well.
check it out: 
www.npersistence.com

If you use NPersistence, you simply map:

```
[Entity]

class ProductPrice

{
    [Id]
    public virtual int Id {get; set;}`

    public virtual int Price {get; set;}
    public virtual int IsSale {get; set;}
    public virtual int Id {get; set;}

    [ManyToOne]
    [Column(Name="SizeProductFk")]
    public virtual ProductSize {get; set;}
}
```